SSL certificate still valid after changing character(s)
I'm making requests with Python's requests module. Due to security concerns its required to verify the servers specific SSL certificate. Two-way-SSL / client certificates are not supported by the server.
I've exported the servers public key (including the CA chain) to a .pem file through a webbrowser. I've set the verify parameter of the requests module to point to the exported .pem file. When I change one or more random characters in the .pem file (in either the server, intermediate or root certificate), there is a reasonable chance that the connection still passes the SSL verification. Changing more characters (quantity) lowers the chance of passing the SSL verification.
My question is how this could happen? Is there some kind of error correction going on in the background? Is there a better way to implement this server authenticity check?

The behavior you’re seeing stems from how SSL verification works, particularly with certificate chains. SSL verification is designed to confirm that a certificate chain leads to a trusted root authority, not to validate every detail of each certificate in the chain. Changing a few characters in the .pem file can sometimes pass if those changes do not interfere with the overall chain's validity or hash integrity.

@Salt could you link me to to applicable documentation about your explanation? And do you have any advise on better ways to implement this authenticity check?

The correct explanation is that changing some base-64 characters (for example, at the end) does not change the bytes they decode to. As always, you should provide an actual modified certificate that exhibits this problem.

For addressing SSL errors in Python, check this article https://scrapeops.io/python-web-scraping-playbook/python-requests-fix-ssl-error/} for practical solutions. To verify authenticity more securely, consider "Direct Hash Verification" by comparing the server's certificate fingerprint against a known hash. Additionally, using a custom SSL context with ssl.SSLContext to load only trusted certificates offers enhanced control, as outlined in the requests documentation. https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/
